# Create new column using str.contains and based on if-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a list of names 'pattern' that I wish to match with strings in column 'url_text'. If there is a match i.e. `True` the name should be printed in a new column 'pol_names_block' and if `False` leave the row empty.

```
pattern = '|'.join(pol_names_list) 

print(pattern)
'Jon Kyl|Doug Jones|Tim Kaine|Lindsey Graham|Cory Booker|Kamala Harris|Orrin Hatch|Bernie Sanders|Thom Tillis|Jerry Moran|Shelly Moore Capito|Maggie Hassan|Tom Carper|Martin Heinrich|Steve Daines|Pat Toomey|Todd Young|Bill Nelson|John Barrasso|Chris Murphy|Mike Rounds|Mike Crapo|John Thune|John. McCain|Susan Collins|Patty Murray|Dianne Feinstein|Claire McCaskill|Lamar Alexander|Jack Reed|Chuck Grassley|Catherine Masto|Pat Roberts|Ben Cardin|Dean Heller|Ron Wyden|Dick Durbin|Jeanne Shaheen|Tammy Duckworth|Sheldon Whitehouse|Tom Cotton|Sherrod Brown|Bob Corker|Tom Udall|Mitch McConnell|James Lankford|Ted Cruz|Mike Enzi|Gary Peters|Jeff Flake|Johnny Isakson|Jim Inhofe|Lindsey Graham|Marco Rubio|Angus King|Kirsten Gillibrand|Bob Casey|Chris Van Hollen|Thad Cochran|Richard Burr|Rob Portman|Jon Tester|Bob Menendez|John Boozman|Mazie Hirono|Joe Manchin|Deb Fischer|Michael Bennet|Debbie Stabenow|Ben Sasse|Brian Schatz|Jim Risch|Mike Lee|Elizabeth Warren|Richard Blumenthal|David Perdue|Al Franken|Bill Cassidy|Cory Gardner|Lisa Murkowski|Maria Cantwell|Tammy Baldwin|Joe Donnelly|Roger Wicker|Amy Klobuchar|Joel Heitkamp|Joni Ernst|Chris Coons|Mark Warner|John Cornyn|Ron Johnson|Patrick Leahy|Chuck Schumer|John Kennedy|Jeff Merkley|Roy Blunt|Richard Shelby|John Hoeven|Rand Paul|Dan Sullivan|Tim Scott|Ed Markey'
```

I am using the following code `df['url_text'].str.contains(pattern)` which results in `True` in case a name in 'pattern' is present in a row in column 'url_text' and `False` otherwise. With that I have tried the following code:

```
df['pol_name_block'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: pol_names_list if df['url_text'].str.contains(pattern) in row['url_text'] else ' ',
    axis=1
)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this toy Dataframe :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
... id,url_text
... 1,Tim Kaine
... 2,Tim Kain
... 3,Tim
... 4,Lindsey Graham.com
... """), sep=',')
>>> df
    id  url_text
0   1   Tim Kaine
1   2   Tim Kain
2   3   Tim
3   4   Lindsey Graham.com
```

From `pol_names_list`, we build `patterns` by formating it like so :

```py
patterns = '(%s)' % '|'.join(pol_names_list)
```

Then, we can use the [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method to assign the value to the column `pol_name_block` to get the expected result :

```py
df['pol_name_block'] = df['url_text'].str.extract(patterns)
```

Output :

```
    id  url_text            pol_name_block
0   1   Tim Kaine           Tim Kaine
1   2   Tim Kain            NaN
2   3   Tim                 NaN
3   4   Lindsey Graham.com  Lindsey Graham
```

Comment: Hi @tlentali. Your answer solves my issue. Thank you.

Comment: @Corralien : +1

Comment: @Corralien : Indeed `findall` and `extractall` are very neat if there is multiple match ! I take the opportunity to tell you that thanks to you I learn a lot in Pandas ! Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge !

Answer (score 2):

Change your pattern to enclose it around a capture group `()` and use `extract`:

```
pattern = fr"({'|'.join(pol_names_list)})"
df['pol_name_block'] = df['url_text'].str.extract(pattern)
print(df)

# Output <- with the sample of @tlentali
   id        url_text  pol_name_block
0   1       Tim Kaine       Tim Kaine
1   2        Tim Kain             NaN
2   3             Tim             NaN
3   4  Lindsey Graham  Lindsey Graham
```

**Important**: you can extract only one element even there are multiple matches. If you want to extract all elements you have to use `findall` or `extractall` (only the output format will change)

```
# New sample, same pattern
>>> df
   id                      url_text
0   1  Tim Kaine and Lindsey Graham
1   2                      Tim Kain
2   3                           Tim
3   4                Lindsey Graham

# findall
>>> df['url_text'].str.findall(pattern)
0    [Tim Kaine, Lindsey Graham]
1                             []
2                             []
3               [Lindsey Graham]
Name: url_text, dtype: object

# extractall
>>> df['url_text'].str.extractall(pattern)
                      0
  match                
0 0           Tim Kaine
  1      Lindsey Graham
3 0      Lindsey Graham
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien. I tried your code and it solves my issue. Thank you very much for taking the time and for following up with an explanation.